# cant get my emails over a month old even though i didnt erase them

Tags: applications, email

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A Model SM-T550 and I'm unable to see any emails older than about two months, but I did not delete the emails. How can I view my older emails?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Gmail app or the default email app, you can set the timeframe in which you want to sync emails by going to **Settings > [youraccount@gmail.com] > Days of mail to sync** (default: 30). Increasing this value will give you a longer history of your emails, but keep in mind that syncing emails over a large timeframe may take up significantly more storage space on your device.

*Note: the wording for "Days of mail to sync" may vary depending on which email app to use.*

Comment: But I think accessing the mail via browser will do the job for him. These problems generally occur when access mail via app.

Comment: The browser version of Gmail, both desktop and mobile, do not limit the time for the history of emails to show. You may want to check your email on a desktop browser (for easier navigation) to make sure that all your emails are still there. You can use "request desktop site" on the Gmail site.

Comment: you can use the search feature of gmail in browser to read a particular mail.